# Stuck transaction after sent a "self" transaction

Tags: transactions, etherscan, pending-transactions, txpool

I tried to buy an item on OpenSea, with low gas. Since the transaction was stuck, I sent an "self" transaction: 0 ETH and higher gas fee, and same nonce:

- https://etherscan.io/tx/0x68115768f34fc90ac2192be5c0d728cfce2bca44ff86c3169b1e9a89c9a570ac

But Etherscan is still showing that the transaction is pending:

- https://etherscan.io/address/0x5b0ccf860b0a6c6c5414b51eda011b4ac2506b0a

When i try to buy another item on OpenSea, I keep receiving a message that a have a transaction with a lower nonce. Clueless on what to do... any help?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug on the Etherscan website. That tx is not pending anymore, though it appears as such when you view your [account](https://etherscan.io/address/0x5b0ccf860b0a6c6c5414b51eda011b4ac2506b0a).

[This tx with nonce 301](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x68115768f34fc90ac2192be5c0d728cfce2bca44ff86c3169b1e9a89c9a570ac) has been dropped and replaced:

[image: Dropped and Replaced]

By [this other tx with nonce 301](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xdcf8e904999493ccd303e085b07347cc231d2f4d62c5420e7233504ad4b52daf).

You can safely continue with your trading on OpenSea knowing that that original tx is not in the mempool anymore. Try to refresh the OpenSea website or reach out to their customer support if the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks Paul, but when i try to buy an item (at open sea) im still getting a message that i have a transaction with a lower nounce still pending (if its a bug, i shouldnt get that message, right?) Will that new transaction complete, knowing that i still have that message?

Comment: According to the public information I have from Etherscan, tx with nonce 301 is done, it has been dropped & replaced. As I said in the answer, for problems with the OpenSea website you should reach out to their customer support. This forum cannot help you with that.